# removing the li jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK so what I'm doing below is adding an input field to the when users click the id #ds. And that adds it the problem is when I try to remove the last li it doesn't remove it. Can some let me know what I did wrong. I'm a newbie to javascript.

```
    var i=3; var ime;

$('#ds').click(function(){

    i++;
    switch(i){
        case 4: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">'; 
            break;
        case 5: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">';
            break;
        case 6: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">'; 
            break;
        case 7: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">'; 
            break;
        case 8: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">';
            break;
        case 9: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">';
            break;
        case 10: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">'; break;
        case 11: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">';   
           break;
        case 12: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">';
            break;
        case 13: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">';
            break;
        case 14: ime='<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Pallet Weight (lbs)" id="QT" class="weight"> <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width (in)" id="QT"><input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height (in)" id="QT">';i=0; 
            break;
    }
    $('ul').append('<li id="Pallet1" class="inactive"><span class="itemNumber">'+i+'</span>'+ime+'</li>');
});

$('#us').click(function(){
    i--;
    $('li:last').prev().remove();
});
```

Comment: because you are not removing the last li, you are removing the previous sibling of the last li... when there is only 1 li remaining there is no previous sibling to remove

Comment: you can't duplicate IDs like that. i would make a temp element, append that, and remove that element the next time by storing a ref to the element itself.

Comment: Why do you have 10 case statements that, as far as I can tell, assign the exact same value to the ime variable?  Can't you do if(i >=4 && i <= 14) {}?  And then if(i==14) { i = 0; } Most times you find yourself repeatedly copy/pasting code, you should probably be doing something different.

Answer (score 0):

It likely has to do with this code here :

```
$('#us').click(function(){
    i--;
    $('li:last').prev().remove();
});
```

Since, you are removing the **previous** `li`, when there is **1** `li` left, there are **0** ***previous*** `li`'s to remove. Thus that last `li` stays there.

So you could try something like this

```
$('#us').click(function(){
    i--;
    $('li:last').prev().remove();

    if ($('li:last').prev().length == 0 || jQuery.isEmptyObject($('li:last').prev()) == true) {
       $('li:last').remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: ok so i edited the li:last to #Pallet1:last and it removes but the problem is that it removes it from the up to bottom

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
  $('#us').click(function () {
     i--;
     if($('li:last').prev().length>0)
        $('li:last').prev().remove();
     else
        $('li:last').remove();
  });
```